# The compile time user.agent value does not match the runtime user.agent value

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, compilation

There is an app I used to run in Mozilla, but I decided to use Chrome. I chose `BlahBlahBlahSafari.gwt.xml` (that contains `<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />`) when compiling project in Eclipse with a help of `Google/GWT Compile` menu option and the right entry point module in Eclipse. As soon as JS is generated when the project is compiled, I thought I wouldn't have any problems. But I got this message:

```
ERROR: Possible problem with your *.gwt.xml module file.
The compile time user.agent value (gecko1_8) does not match the runtime user.agent value (safari). Expect more errors.
```

Arguments in the `Run Configurations...` menu in Eclipse seems to be okay. What can be a reason for such a behavior and what didn't I take into account? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

GWT provides the option of compiling javascript for a set of browsers. This configuration is done in your module XMl file `BlahBlahBlahSafari.gwt.xml`. It is done using:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6,gecko,gecko1_8" />
```

This works for IE and Firefox. To compile the javascript only for Chrome, use:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

Comment: Yep, I know that, in my case there is a `value="safari"`.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely solution to this is that your changes to `BlahBlahBlahSafari.gwt.xml` are not picked up. You said you set `user.agent` to `safari` and load the compiled app in Chrome. Which is a perfect match. The message "The compile time user.agent value (gecko1_8) ..." tells you that the app you're loading was actually not compiled for Chrome, it was compiled for gecko1_8.

Make sure the folder you're compiling to is actually the folder you think you compile to. Make sure you really open the freshly compiled files in your browser and not an old copy of your old app. Make sure the app loader (the `*.nocache.js`) is really not cached. If you use super dev mode, make sure the code server does not run the old version of your app (restart the code server or let the code server recompile the module).

Answer (score 0):

Check also any imported GWT modules for user.agent declarations